# Andoid's webview apk app not working. JQuery works on the web app but the same functions don't do what they should be on the mobile version

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, android-webview

I'm working on a web app for a client, which might be a game-changer so for some reasons it has to remain classified.
The web app is working completely fine but the converted version of the Android app is giving me issues when it comes to doing the same functions in JQuery. Any idea at all why something like this might be happening?

I know I did not give enough information but all I need is to know what might cause an issue like.
I did enable JavaScript before publishing the app but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

try this... may be this will help you

```
WebView vistaWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
vistaWeb.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient(this));
vistaWeb.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient(this));
vistaWeb.clearCache(true);
vistaWeb.clearHistory();
vistaWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
vistaWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

or try this

```
   webview.setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient())
    webview.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
    webview.clearCache(true)
    webview.clearHistory()
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true)
```

Comment: Hey @Nidheesh.. Thanks for the suggestion, it nudged me into the right direction and I discovered that below "setJavaScriptEnabled(true)", I was supposed to add "setDOMStorageEnabled(true)" since my JQuery handles data and sorts it using a set of delimiters provided in the string.

Thank you for your suggestion.